# How to compute the mean and standard deviation of all the corresponding elements in the list of two dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, mean

I have a list of two data frames say df1 and df2. df1 and df2 are given below,

df1 = [image] and df2 = [image]

Also, `listOfDataframe = [df1,df2]`

df1 and df2 can be generated as follows,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[99,85,93], [89,97,94], [80,95,89]]), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns = ["Sensetivity", "specificity", "Accuracy"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[85,99,50], [97,89,75], [95,80,60]]), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns = ["Sensetivity", "specificity", "Accuracy"])
```

Now, I want to compute the mean and standard deviation of the corresponding elements in two data frames, which are sitting inside a list `listOfDataframe`. How can we do that in a simplistic way? I want a single output data frame as follows,

output = [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: include your data as text, not pictures.

Comment: I have now added the data in the text format using python code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
listOfDataframe = [df1,df2]
stats = (pd.concat(listOfDataframe).groupby(level=0).agg(['mean','std'])
           .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
           .round(0).astype(str)   # modify this as you wish
        )

out = stats['mean'] + '±' + stats['std']
```

Output:

```
  Sensetivity specificity   Accuracy
A   92.0±10.0   92.0±10.0  72.0±30.0
B    93.0±6.0    93.0±6.0  84.0±13.0
C   88.0±11.0   88.0±11.0  74.0±21.0
```